# Compare 2 lists and add the matching into a map of object using Java8

Tags: java-8

I need some help on a java8. Basically I have 2 lists of different type. I need to compare both and add it to map. Here is my code that I tried. I am stuck here and need help

```
Dto{
     String name,
     String id,
     String address;
 }

 strList = dtoList.stream().map(Dto::getName()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

   Map<String,Object> map= new HashMap<>();
      List<Dto> newList = newArrayList<>();
      List<Dto> dtoList = data1;
      List<String> strList  = data2;
     
        for(Dto dto: dtoList ){
           strList .stream().filter(x->x.equals(dto.getName()).findAny().ifPresent(y-> {
                newList.add(dto) // I need to add dto into list
         }
           map.put(x, newList);

        }.
```

There will be list of objects--newList for every single strList. How to proceed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show an example for input and output ?

Comment: Yes I have added it.

Comment: Could you please provide a compilable code? This is really hard to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.groupingBy` to collect `Dto` group by name in `Map<String, List<Dto>>` where key is `name` and value is all the `Dto` having the same `name`. You don't need to collect names before like in `strList` as this information already in `Dto`, you can use it for `groupingBy` directly.

```
Map<String, List<Dto>> map = dtoList.stream()
                                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> d.getName()));
```

**Update**: To collect as `Map<String, Object>`

```
Map<String, Object> map = dtoList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> d.getName(), 
                  Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), e -> (Object)e)));
```

Comment: I need to compare 2 lists and then add it to map-- dtoList and strList

Comment: You don't need to collect names before like strList as this information already inside dto you can use it for grouping dto by name. Answer updated some explanation also

Comment: Thanks. I need the map to have string and object. Internally yes it will be list<Dto>. But when returning from the method i need to retain map<String, Object> for some other purpose.Some other source needs of this format

Comment: Thanks Rono. But when I try to perform  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> d.getName(),---- It is not pointing to dtoList but instead to object. So i am not able to add d->d.getName(). It says cannot infer type arguments.

Comment: @user14288342 That's work for me. You can test online [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/HJhUl8GSw)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help. I just added Map<String, Object> map = dtoList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Dto::getName(), 
                  Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), e -> (Object)e)));